# BeanValidation 1.1: link violation to parameter

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation, jsr349

The `ExecutableValidator.validateParameters` API allows it to validate parameters of an method invocation.

However when it returns back with a set of `ConstraintViolations`, how can I link the violation element in the set to a specific parameter (say, by index)?

Think about I need to validate a controller method invocation when user post a form. Once I found there are errors in the data through the `validateParameters` API, I need to come back to user by saying your value of `xxx` field is invalid. I do need to know which parameter value caused a specific violation.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

So the answer is inside the [ConstraintViolation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html), which has a property named [propertyPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html#getPropertyPath--), with type [javax.validation.Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Path.html)

Each path is composed with a list of [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Path.Node.html). Within the node list, there is one node `NodeImpl.ParamNodeImpl`. If you `toString()` the param node impl, it returns something look like `arg0`, `arg1`, `arg2` ... and those `0`, `1`, `1` is corresponding to the failed parameter index.